# AWS Elastic Beanstalk gives "could not translate host name "db" to address" error

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been trying to deploy my docker consisted of Django, Postgresql and Nginx. It works fine when I do

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

However when deploy it on AWS EB, it gives me

```
could not translate host name "db" to address: Name or service not known
```

What I've done is I pushed my docker to docker hub using

```
sudo docker build -t myname/dockername -f Dockerfile .
```

and I simply do

```
eb deploy
```

**File Structure**

```
myproject
    myproject
        settings.py
        urls.py
        ...
    Dockerfile
    Dockerrun.aws.json
    manage.py
    requirements.txt
    ...
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["sh", "on-container-start.sh"]
```

**Dockerrun.aws.json**

```
{
 "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
 "Image": {
   "Name": "myname/dockername:latest",
   "Update": "true"
 },
 "Ports": [
   {
     "ContainerPort": "8000"
   }
 ]
}
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    hostname: db
    networks:
     - some_network
  web:
    restart: always
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    hostname: web
    expose:
      - "8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db:db
    networks:
      - some_network
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    hostname: nginx
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - web
    networks:
      - some_network
networks:
  some_network:
```

One thing I realize is that when I use docker-compose up on my machine, I get 3 different containers running. However on EB, I see only one container running.

I think it's because I'm fetching the image from docker hub that I built with those files and that somehow caused these 3 containers to be one and it's messing up with recognizing host names? I am quite not sure still. Help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: are you using same docker-compose file in both case ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `Dockerrun.aws.json` should correlate with `docker-compose.yml`

The reason of issue that host name ”db“ could not be translated to address  is that the `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerrun.aws.json` files describe a different architecture:

- There are 3 containers in `docker-compose.yml`
- There is only 1 container in `Dockerrun.aws.json`

Therefore, the application tries to resolve the `db` hostname and cannot find it, because `db` not declared in `Dockerrun.aws.json`

## Fix `Dockerrun.aws.json`

So, update your `Dockerrun.aws.json`. You can do it either manually or using convenient tool [micahhausler/container-transform](https://github.com/micahhausler/container-transform):

### a) either update it manually

You can use samples, such as:

- [k2works/aws-eb-docker-multi-container-sample](https://github.com/k2works/aws-eb-docker-multi-container-sample)**

### b) or update it  using `micahhausler/container-transform`

You can try [micahhausler/container-transform](https://github.com/micahhausler/container-transform):

> Transforms docker-compose, ECS, and Marathon configurations
> Transforms docker-compose, ECS, and Marathon configurations

Here is what it outputs for your case:

```bash
$ container-transform docker-compose.yml > Dockerrun.aws.json
```

**Dockerrun.aws.json**

```json
{
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "essential": true,
            "image": "postgres",
            "name": "db"
        },
        {
            "essential": true,
            "image": "nginx",
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "containerPath": "/etc/nginx/conf.d",
                    "sourceVolume": "_ConfigNginx"
                }
            ],
            "name": "nginx",
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 8000,
                    "hostPort": 8000
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "essential": true,
            "links": [
                "db:db"
            ],
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "containerPath": "/code",
                    "sourceVolume": "_"
                }
            ],
            "name": "web"
        }
    ],
    "family": "",
    "volumes": [
        {
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "."
            },
            "name": "_"
        },
        {
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "./config/nginx"
            },
            "name": "_ConfigNginx"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Note:**: Of course, you should fix missing settings such as `memory` for `db` and `nginx` containers.

## You can omit `networks` at all

According to [Networking in Compose | Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/):

> For example, suppose your app is in a directory called `myapp`, and your `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "8001:5432"
```

> When you run `docker-compose up`, the following happens:
>
> 1. A network called `myapp_default` is created.
> 2. A container is created using `web`’s configuration. It joins the network `myapp_default` under the name `web`.
> 3. A container is created using `db`’s configuration. It joins the network `myapp_default` under the name `db`.

So, since all your containers linked to the same `some_network`, you can omit it.

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    hostname: db
  web:
    restart: always
    build: .
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    hostname: web
    expose:
      - "8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db:db
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    hostname: nginx
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - web
```

And `$ container-transform docker-compose.yml > Dockerrun.aws.json` will produce:

**Dockerrun.aws.json**

```json
{
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "essential": true,
            "image": "postgres",
            "name": "db"
        },
        {
            "essential": true,
            "image": "nginx",
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "containerPath": "/etc/nginx/conf.d",
                    "sourceVolume": "_ConfigNginx"
                }
            ],
            "name": "nginx",
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 8000,
                    "hostPort": 8000
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "essential": true,
            "links": [
                "db:db"
            ],
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "containerPath": "/code",
                    "sourceVolume": "_"
                }
            ],
            "name": "web"
        }
    ],
    "family": "",
    "volumes": [
        {
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "."
            },
            "name": "_"
        },
        {
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "./config/nginx"
            },
            "name": "_ConfigNginx"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me out! However now I'm facing `ERROR   ECS task stopped due to: Task failed to start. (nginx: CannotCreateContainerError: Error response from daemon: create ./config/nginx: "./config/nginx" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path
db: 
web: )
` from aws side. Is this is nginx.conf issue? Again, thank you so much!!

Comment: @Jason, as usual, nginx config is stored in somewhere like  `/etc/nginx/conf` . For your case, try absolute path instead of `./config/nginx`