# Deploy a Django project to AWS EB using Docker and nginx

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx

Currently, I try to deploy a Django project to AWS EB but I'm facing a lot of problems. I could dockerize the project and deploy it on the AWS elastic beanstalk. But when I try to access the site I always see: 502 Bad Gateway. Locally, the project runs smoothly. I am not really into nginx and I have no idea how to solve this problem.

This is my project structure:
[image: Project structure]

This is my Dockerfile:

```
# Creating image based on official python3 image
FROM python:3

MAINTAINER Jaron Bardenhagen

# Sets dumping log messages directly to stream instead of buffering
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Creating and putting configurations
RUN mkdir /config
ADD config/app /config/

# Installing all python dependencies
RUN pip install -r /config/requirements.txt

# Open port 8000 to outside world
EXPOSE 8000

# When container starts, this script will be executed.
# Note that it is NOT executed during building
CMD ["sh", "/config/on-container-start.sh"]

# Creating and putting application inside container
# and setting it to working directory (meaning it is going to be default)
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD app /app/
```

This is my docker-compose file:

```
# File structure version
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB_PORT: "5432"
      POSTGRES_DB_HOST: "*******"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "*******"
      POSTGRES_USER: Jaron
      POSTGRES_DB: ebdb
  # Build from remote dockerfile
  # Connect local app folder with image folder, so changes will be pushed to image instantly
  # Open port 8000
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: config/app/Dockerfile
    hostname: app
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    expose:
      - "8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  # Web server based on official nginx image
  # Connect external 8000 (which you can access from browser)
  # with internal port 8000(which will be linked to app port 8000 in configs)
  # Connect local nginx configuration with image configuration
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    hostname: nginx
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    depends_on:
      - app
```

This is the Dockerrun.aws File:

```
{
 "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
 "Image": {
   "Name": "******/******:latest",
   "Update": "true"
 },
 "Ports": [
   {
     "ContainerPort": "8000"
   }
 ]
}
```

On-container-start.sh file:

```
# Create migrations based on django models
python manage.py makemigrations

# Migrate created migrations to database
python manage.py migrate
# Start gunicorn server at port 8000 and keep an eye for app code changes
# If changes occur, kill worker and start a new one
gunicorn --reload project.wsgi:application -b 0.0.0.0:8000
```

And here is the file for the nginx settings (app.conf):

```
# define group app
upstream app {
  # balancing by ip
  ip_hash;

  # define server app
  server app:8000;
}

# portal
server {

  # all other requests proxies to app
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://app/;
  }

  # only respond to port 8000
  listen 8000;

  # domain localhost
  server_name localhost;
}
```

I really appreciate any kind of help!

Comment: This may help you: https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/502-bad-gateway

Answer (score 0):

- First check this question on stack overflow: [link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57684920/aws-elastic-beanstalk-gives-could-not-translate-host-name-db-to-address-erro).
  If this doesn't solve your problem try the below suggestion.
- Try to replace the postgress database with RDS and make sure your RDS and EB environment are in the same VPC. I had this problem when I tried to deploy django project on EB.
- Removing Postgress docker image and connecting it with RDS solved my issue.
- For some reason, EB is stopping postgress images.